# Artifacts List page is blank

Tags: temple-run-2

Few days ago I noticed the artifacts page is blank 
There should be 70 some unclaimed artifacts 
What happened?

[image] [image]

Comment: The page was recently changed, and the change appears to me to have really degraded performance (rendering is slow, scrolling/changing takes time). Perhaps with that many unclaimed artifacts it's just taking a really long time to display properly?